# I get "Certificate Verify Failed" on installing Bundler for Ruby on Rails, on Windows 7. Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, certificate, verify

I've tried everything what I understood in my short knowladge of Programming.

When I enter "bundler install" I get "Certificate Verify Failed" (I've checked the certificate, it's updated) Then it ends up with "Make sure "gem install [gem's name] -v [version]  succeds before bundling."

So I decided to install Gem-per-Gem, instead of trying to solve they certificate issue.

Will this work or I'm just wasting my time?

Comment: I am having a similar issue when attempting to update or install anything gem related...not certain how this all works and I'm trying to find a better understanding of what's going on as well...will keep this stream posted with anything that works for me

Answer (score 26):

Found it!

https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

Most importantly...download 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem

Figure out where to stick it

```
C:\>gem which rubygems
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb
```

Then just copy the .pem file in ../2.1.0/rubygems/ssl_certs/ and go on about your business.

**NOTE**
The above link is currently down as of 10/12/2016. Commentary led me to do some follow-up research and it appears to be a continuing problem and is not being directly discussed. There are other topics directly on the rubygems KB you may want to follow --> http://help.rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SSL+Certs&t=d&scope=all&category_id=&recommend=1

Comment: Some browsers (e.g. Chrome) may save the .pem file as `.txt`, be sure to change this back to just `.pem`.

Comment: The download link doesn't work anymore. Is there any alternate download link?

Comment: Try updating to the latest bundler gem. The new certs are bundled starting with version 1.12.0.

Comment: The .pem file listed here (and on the gitub gist link in this answer) is now a 404. Suggestions?

Comment: The certificate is here now: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bundler/bundler/master/lib/bundler/ssl_certs/rubygems.org/AddTrustExternalCARoot.pem

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing **'https://rubygems.org'** with **http://rubygems.org** in the GemFile